# Do I need to upgrade?

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using today few different methodologies to upload content to you-tube, and I don't know if I have to upgrade any of them or all of them to API V3.

1. We send feed XML using SFTP, see code: https://github.com/kaltura/server/blob/Jupiter-10.8.0/plugins/content_distribution/providers/youtube/lib/feed/YouTubeDistributionRightsFeedHelper.php
2. We update playlists using the API, see the client lib we use: https://github.com/kaltura/server/blob/Jupiter-10.8.0/vendor/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php#L995
3. We send XML using SFTP using XML older template: github.com/kaltura/server/blob/Jupiter-10.8.0/plugins/content_distribution/providers/youtube/xml_templates/feed_template.xml
4. We use Zend_Gdata_YouTube, see code: github.com/kaltura/server/blob/Jupiter-10.8.0/vendor/ZendFramework/library/Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php

Thanks,
T.

Comment: You can never go wrong if you upgrade to the next version of an API. The old ones can have support cut or removed entirely.

Comment: You're sepcifically using some v2 endpoints (see my search [here](https://github.com/kaltura/server/search?p=1&q=%22youtube.com%22&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)).  I'd strongly recommend you update your app to use v3 endpoints.